# How to inject services in angular storybook components?

Tags: angular, storybook, angular-storybook

Github: https://github.com/danielhdz56/storybook-demo.git

Injecting a service in a component always throws an error in storybook:

```
Error: Can't resolve all parameters for CustomService: (?).
```

an example component:

```
 @Component({
   selector: 'app-custom-selector',
   templateUrl: './custom-selector.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./custom-selector.component.scss'],
 })
 export class NavigationItemComponent {
   constructor(private customService: CustomService) {}
 }
```

Comment: can you post the code for `CustomService` here

Comment: Please post the `CustomService` code and then we will find a way to help you.

Comment: @PardeepJain Added github: https://github.com/danielhdz56/storybook-demo.git

Answer (score 2):

Yo need to add them in the module metaData

```
const modules = {
    imports: [..],
    providers: [CustomService],
    declarations: [NavigationItemComponent ]
};

// Then in stories: 
.add('description',
    () => ({
        component: NavigationItemComponent ,
        props: {...},
        moduleMetadata: modules
    }
)
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. I added a github example: https://github.com/danielhdz56/storybook-demo.git

Comment: Probably that's a bug on their side then. https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/7722

Comment: You dont have to declare anything if you just have `providedIn: 'root'` in your Service.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by using a custom factory initializer for the needed service when **not** using an additional host component with the help of `APP_INITIALIZER` from `@angular/core`:

```
import { APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';

function myServiceFactory(myService: MyService) {
  return () => myService;
}

const meta: Meta<MyCustomComponent> = {
  title: 'Components/Custom component',
  component: MyCustomComponent,
  argTypes: {},
  decorators: [
    moduleMetadata({
      imports: [
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        BrowserModule,
        CommonModule,
      ],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
          useFactory: myServiceFactory,
          deps: [MyService]
        }
      ]
    }),
  ],
};
```